# Haskell pattern matching warning

Tags: haskell

im relatively new to Haskell (third day learning the language) and am having a problem with pattern matching. I have defined the function `doubleEveryOther` below and as far as I can see I have covered the three possible scenarios: empty list, list of length == 1 and list length > 1. The code compiles fine but when a try to use the function it throw a non-exhaustive pattern match error:

```
*** Exception: ex2.hs:(3,1)-(5,55): Non-exhaustive patterns in function doubleEveryOther
```

I have then enabled warnings in GHCI, and found the following warning when I load the ex2.hs file:

```
ex2.hs:3:1: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for `doubleEveryOther':
        Patterns not matched: _ : (_ : (_ : _))
```

Line 3:1 refers to the empty case which I think I have covered with `doubleEveryOther [] = []`

I cant see where I have gone wrong here. Help appreciated.

Cheers,

```
-- file: ex2.hs
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther [] = []
doubleEveryOther (x:[]) = [x]
doubleEveryOther (_:[xs]) = take (length [xs] - 1) [xs]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the third pattern:

```
doubleEveryOther (_:[xs])
```

This pattern matches the case of a list with two elements (since `x:[xs]` is equivalent to `[x,xs]`). The correct syntax is:

```
doubleEveryOther (_:xs)
```

Comment: Got it. I currently have patterns for empty, 1 and 2, but not 2 or more. Changing it to the above gives patterns for empty, 1 and 2 or more. Thanks. Do you have any idea why the warning is referncing the line containing the second pattern and not the third (line 3 rather than 4)? Ive been having problems correcting my code using the warning messages, and this is probably a big factor.

Comment: @Dave0504 I think it's just referring to the first line of the pattern matching. Note that in the GHC warning, it gives the whole span: (3,1)-(5,55)

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
doubleEveryOther (_:[xs]) = take (length [xs] - 1) [xs]
```

matches a two-element list i.e. an unbound head followed by a single-element list containing the element `xs`. You should use

```
doubleEveryOther (_:xs) = take (length xs - 1) xs
```

instead of `take (n-1)` you can use `drop 1`:

```
doubleEveryOther (_:xs) = drop xs
```

or using a match:

```
(_:_:xs) = xs
```

You probably also want to make a recursive call in this case.